# Reuse PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java

I have implemented `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`. How can I make `client` reusable, so other class can reuse it? Should I put it in a `Service`?

```
public class MyClass() {

  private static CloseableHttpClient client;
  private static final CookieStore commonCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
  private static final ScheduledExecutorService cleanUpThread = ScheduledExecutorService.wrap(
            new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1), "connection-pool-cleanup-thread-%d");

  public MyClass() {
      try {
            String keystoreId = //getKeyStoreId()
            if (client == null) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(keystoreId)) {
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConSocFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(TLSSocketFactoryCache.getInstance().get(keystoreId),
                            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
                    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                            .register("https", sslConSocFactory).build();

                    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setConnectTimeout(1000)
                            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000)
                            .setSocketTimeout(1000)
                            .build();

                    ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
                        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                            // Honor 'keep-alive' header
                            HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
                                    response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                                String param = he.getName();
                                String value = he.getValue();
                                if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                                    try {
                                        return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                                    } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                                        // ignore
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            try {
                                return 60000;
                            } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                                // ignore
                            }
                            // otherwise keep alive for 60 seconds
                            return 60 * 1000;
                        }
                    };

                    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
                    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);
                    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
                    connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(60000);

                    client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                            .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                            .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
                            .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy())
                            .setUserTokenHandler(context -> null)
                            .setMaxConnTotal(200)
                            .setMaxConnPerRoute(200)
                            .setConnectionTimeToLive(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .build();

                    int closeIdle = 60000;
                    cleanUpThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                        try {
                            connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
                            connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(closeIdle, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            LOGGER.error("Exception on SGW clean up thread", ex);
                        }
                    }, closeIdle, closeIdle, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Error! No keystore specified");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Encountered exception during retrieval of SSL Context", e);
        }
  }

}
```